# ggplot partially recognises categorical against time data in geom_ribbon

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, categorical-data

I am trying to plot a person's daily activities (Non-working hours, At work, or Driving) in relation to his physiological status (labelled as 'Code_response') against time.

I use ggplot geom_ribbon to visualise his daily activities, but realising the colour was only partially filled. This especially applies to the transitions between 'at work' and 'driving' periods.

My data looks like the following

```
dput(A9)    
A9  Date    Time    Code_Activity   Code_Activity1
185 15/09/2015  02:04:00    0   1
186 15/09/2015  02:05:00    0   1
187 15/09/2015  02:06:00    0   1
188 15/09/2015  02:07:00    0   1
189 15/09/2015  02:08:00    0   1
190 15/09/2015  02:09:00    0   1
191 15/09/2015  02:10:00    0   1
192 15/09/2015  02:11:00    0   1
193 15/09/2015  02:12:00    0   1
194 15/09/2015  02:13:00    0   1
195 15/09/2015  02:14:00    0   1
196 15/09/2015  02:15:00    0   1
197 15/09/2015  02:16:00    0   1
198 15/09/2015  02:17:00    0   1
199 15/09/2015  02:18:00    0   1
200 15/09/2015  02:19:00    0   1
201 15/09/2015  02:20:00    0   1
202 15/09/2015  02:21:00    0   1
203 15/09/2015  02:22:00    0   1
204 15/09/2015  02:23:00    0   1
205 15/09/2015  02:24:00    0   1
206 15/09/2015  02:25:00    0   1
207 15/09/2015  02:26:00    0   1
208 15/09/2015  02:27:00    0   1
209 15/09/2015  02:28:00    0   1
210 15/09/2015  02:29:00    0   1
211 15/09/2015  02:30:00    0   1
212 15/09/2015  02:31:00    0   1
213 15/09/2015  02:32:00    0   1
214 15/09/2015  02:33:00    0   1
215 15/09/2015  02:34:00    0   1
216 15/09/2015  02:35:00    0   1
217 15/09/2015  02:36:00    0   1
218 15/09/2015  02:37:00    0   1
219 15/09/2015  02:38:00    0   1
220 15/09/2015  02:39:00    0   1
221 15/09/2015  02:40:00    0   1
222 15/09/2015  02:41:00    0   1
223 15/09/2015  02:42:00    0   1
224 15/09/2015  02:43:00    0   1
225 15/09/2015  02:44:00    0   1
226 15/09/2015  02:45:00    0   1
227 15/09/2015  02:46:00    0   1
228 15/09/2015  02:47:00    0   1
229 15/09/2015  02:48:00    0   1
230 15/09/2015  02:49:00    0   1
231 15/09/2015  02:50:00    0   1
232 15/09/2015  02:51:00    0   1
233 15/09/2015  02:52:00    0   1
234 15/09/2015  02:53:00    0   1
235 15/09/2015  02:54:00    0   1
236 15/09/2015  02:55:00    0   1
237 15/09/2015  02:56:00    0   1
238 15/09/2015  02:57:00    0   1
239 15/09/2015  02:58:00    0   1
240 15/09/2015  02:59:00    0   1
241 15/09/2015  03:00:00    0   1
242 15/09/2015  03:01:00    0   1
243 15/09/2015  03:02:00    0   1
244 15/09/2015  03:03:00    0   1
245 15/09/2015  03:04:00    0   1
246 15/09/2015  03:05:00    0   1
247 15/09/2015  03:06:00    0   1
248 15/09/2015  03:07:00    0   1
249 15/09/2015  03:08:00    0   1
250 15/09/2015  03:09:00    0   1
251 15/09/2015  03:10:00    0   1
252 15/09/2015  03:11:00    0   1
253 15/09/2015  03:12:00    0   1
254 15/09/2015  03:13:00    0   1
255 15/09/2015  03:14:00    0   1
256 15/09/2015  03:15:00    0   1
257 15/09/2015  03:16:00    0   1
258 15/09/2015  03:17:00    0   1
259 15/09/2015  03:18:00    0   1
260 15/09/2015  03:19:00    0   1
261 15/09/2015  03:20:00    0   1
262 15/09/2015  03:21:00    0   1
263 15/09/2015  03:22:00    0   1
264 15/09/2015  03:23:00    0   1
265 15/09/2015  03:24:00    0   1
266 15/09/2015  03:25:00    0   1
267 15/09/2015  03:26:00    0   1
268 15/09/2015  03:27:00    0   1
269 15/09/2015  03:28:00    0   1
270 15/09/2015  03:29:00    0   1
271 15/09/2015  03:30:00    0   1
272 15/09/2015  03:31:00    0   1
273 15/09/2015  03:32:00    0   1
274 15/09/2015  03:33:00    0   1
275 15/09/2015  03:34:00    0   1
276 15/09/2015  03:35:00    0   1
277 15/09/2015  03:36:00    0   1
278 15/09/2015  03:37:00    0   1
279 15/09/2015  03:38:00    0   1
280 15/09/2015  03:39:00    0   1
281 15/09/2015  03:40:00    0   1
282 15/09/2015  03:41:00    0   1
283 15/09/2015  03:42:00    0   1
284 15/09/2015  03:43:00    0   1
285 15/09/2015  03:44:00    0   1
286 15/09/2015  03:45:00    0   1
287 15/09/2015  03:46:00    0   1
288 15/09/2015  03:47:00    0   1
289 15/09/2015  03:48:00    0   1
290 15/09/2015  03:49:00    0   1
291 15/09/2015  03:50:00    0   1
292 15/09/2015  03:51:00    0   1
293 15/09/2015  03:52:00    0   1
294 15/09/2015  03:53:00    0   1
295 15/09/2015  03:54:00    0   1
296 15/09/2015  03:55:00    0   1
297 15/09/2015  03:56:00    0   1
298 15/09/2015  03:57:00    0   1
299 15/09/2015  03:58:00    0   1
300 15/09/2015  03:59:00    0   1
301 15/09/2015  04:00:00    0   1
302 15/09/2015  04:01:00    0   1
303 15/09/2015  04:02:00    0   1
304 15/09/2015  04:03:00    0   1
305 15/09/2015  04:04:00    0   1
306 15/09/2015  04:05:00    0   1
307 15/09/2015  04:06:00    0   1
308 15/09/2015  04:07:00    0   1
309 15/09/2015  04:08:00    0   1
310 15/09/2015  04:09:00    0   1
311 15/09/2015  04:10:00    0   1
312 15/09/2015  04:11:00    0   1
313 15/09/2015  04:12:00    0   1
314 15/09/2015  04:13:00    0   1
315 15/09/2015  04:14:00    0   1
316 15/09/2015  04:15:00    0   1
317 15/09/2015  04:16:00    0   1
318 15/09/2015  04:17:00    0   1
319 15/09/2015  04:18:00    0   1
320 15/09/2015  04:19:00    0   1
321 15/09/2015  04:20:00    0   1
322 15/09/2015  04:21:00    0   1
323 15/09/2015  04:22:00    0   1
324 15/09/2015  04:23:00    0   1
325 15/09/2015  04:24:00    0   1
326 15/09/2015  04:25:00    0   1
327 15/09/2015  04:26:00    0   1
328 15/09/2015  04:27:00    0   1
329 15/09/2015  04:28:00    0   1
330 15/09/2015  04:29:00    0   1
331 15/09/2015  04:30:00    0   1
332 15/09/2015  04:31:00    0   1
333 15/09/2015  04:32:00    0   1
334 15/09/2015  04:33:00    0   1
335 15/09/2015  04:34:00    0   1
336 15/09/2015  04:35:00    0   1
337 15/09/2015  04:36:00    0   1
338 15/09/2015  04:37:00    0   1
339 15/09/2015  04:38:00    0   1
340 15/09/2015  04:39:00    0   1
341 15/09/2015  04:40:00    0   1
342 15/09/2015  04:41:00    0   1
343 15/09/2015  04:42:00    0   1
344 15/09/2015  04:43:00    0   1
345 15/09/2015  04:44:00    0   1
346 15/09/2015  04:45:00    0   1
347 15/09/2015  04:46:00    0   1
348 15/09/2015  04:47:00    0   1
349 15/09/2015  04:48:00    0   1
350 15/09/2015  04:49:00    0   1
351 15/09/2015  04:50:00    0   1
352 15/09/2015  04:51:00    0   1
353 15/09/2015  04:52:00    0   1
354 15/09/2015  04:53:00    0   1
355 15/09/2015  04:54:00    0   1
356 15/09/2015  04:55:00    0   1
357 15/09/2015  04:56:00    0   1
358 15/09/2015  04:57:00    0   1
359 15/09/2015  04:58:00    0   1
360 15/09/2015  04:59:00    0   1
361 15/09/2015  05:00:00    0   1
362 15/09/2015  05:01:00    0   1
363 15/09/2015  05:02:00    0   1
364 15/09/2015  05:03:00    0   1
365 15/09/2015  05:04:00    0   1
366 15/09/2015  05:05:00    0   1
367 15/09/2015  05:06:00    0   1
368 15/09/2015  05:07:00    0   1
369 15/09/2015  05:08:00    0   1
370 15/09/2015  05:09:00    0   1
371 15/09/2015  05:10:00    0   1
372 15/09/2015  05:11:00    0   1
373 15/09/2015  05:12:00    0   1
374 15/09/2015  05:13:00    0   1
375 15/09/2015  05:14:00    0   1
376 15/09/2015  05:15:00    0   1
377 15/09/2015  05:16:00    0   1
378 15/09/2015  05:17:00    0   1
379 15/09/2015  05:18:00    0   1
380 15/09/2015  05:19:00    0   1
381 15/09/2015  05:20:00    0   1
382 15/09/2015  05:21:00    0   1
383 15/09/2015  05:22:00    0   1
384 15/09/2015  05:23:00    0   1
385 15/09/2015  05:24:00    0   1
386 15/09/2015  05:25:00    0   1
387 15/09/2015  05:26:00    0   1
388 15/09/2015  05:27:00    0   1
389 15/09/2015  05:28:00    0   1
390 15/09/2015  05:29:00    0   1
391 15/09/2015  05:30:00    0   1
392 15/09/2015  05:31:00    0   1
393 15/09/2015  05:32:00    0   1
394 15/09/2015  05:33:00    0   1
395 15/09/2015  05:34:00    0   1
396 15/09/2015  05:35:00    0   1
397 15/09/2015  05:36:00    0   1
398 15/09/2015  05:37:00    0   1
399 15/09/2015  05:38:00    0   1
400 15/09/2015  05:39:00    0   1
401 15/09/2015  05:40:00    0   1
402 15/09/2015  05:41:00    0   1
403 15/09/2015  05:42:00    0   1
404 15/09/2015  05:43:00    0   1
405 15/09/2015  05:44:00    0   1
406 15/09/2015  05:45:00    0   1
407 15/09/2015  05:46:00    0   1
408 15/09/2015  05:47:00    0   1
409 15/09/2015  05:48:00    0   1
410 15/09/2015  05:49:00    0   1
411 15/09/2015  05:50:00    0   1
412 15/09/2015  05:51:00    0   1
413 15/09/2015  05:52:00    0   1
414 15/09/2015  05:53:00    0   1
415 15/09/2015  05:54:00    0   1
416 15/09/2015  05:55:00    0   1
417 15/09/2015  05:56:00    0   1
418 15/09/2015  05:57:00    0   1
419 15/09/2015  05:58:00    0   1
420 15/09/2015  05:59:00    0   1
421 15/09/2015  06:00:00    0   1
422 15/09/2015  06:01:00    0   1
423 15/09/2015  06:02:00    0   1
424 15/09/2015  06:03:00    0   1
425 15/09/2015  06:04:00    0   1
426 15/09/2015  06:05:00    0   1
427 15/09/2015  06:06:00    0   1
428 15/09/2015  06:07:00    0   1
429 15/09/2015  06:08:00    0   1
430 15/09/2015  06:09:00    0   1
431 15/09/2015  06:10:00    0   1
432 15/09/2015  06:11:00    0   1
433 15/09/2015  06:12:00    0   1
434 15/09/2015  06:13:00    0   1
435 15/09/2015  06:14:00    0   1
436 15/09/2015  06:15:00    0   1
437 15/09/2015  06:16:00    0   1
438 15/09/2015  06:17:00    0   1
439 15/09/2015  06:18:00    0   1
440 15/09/2015  06:19:00    0   1
441 15/09/2015  06:20:00    0   1
442 15/09/2015  06:21:00    0   1
443 15/09/2015  06:22:00    0   1
444 15/09/2015  06:23:00    0   1
445 15/09/2015  06:24:00    0   1
446 15/09/2015  06:25:00    0   1
447 15/09/2015  06:26:00    0   1
448 15/09/2015  06:27:00    0   1
449 15/09/2015  06:28:00    0   1
450 15/09/2015  06:29:00    0   1
451 15/09/2015  06:30:00    0   1
452 15/09/2015  06:31:00    0   1
453 15/09/2015  06:32:00    0   1
454 15/09/2015  06:33:00    0   1
455 15/09/2015  06:34:00    0   1
456 15/09/2015  06:35:00    0   1
457 15/09/2015  06:36:00    0   1
458 15/09/2015  06:37:00    0   1
459 15/09/2015  06:38:00    0   1
460 15/09/2015  06:39:00    0   1
461 15/09/2015  06:40:00    0   1
462 15/09/2015  06:41:00    0   1
463 15/09/2015  06:42:00    0   1
464 15/09/2015  06:43:00    0   1
465 15/09/2015  06:44:00    0   1
466 15/09/2015  06:45:00    1   2
467 15/09/2015  06:46:00    1   2
468 15/09/2015  06:47:00    1   2
469 15/09/2015  06:48:00    1   2
470 15/09/2015  06:49:00    1   2
471 15/09/2015  06:50:00    1   2
472 15/09/2015  06:51:00    1   2
473 15/09/2015  06:52:00    1   2
474 15/09/2015  06:53:00    1   2
475 15/09/2015  06:54:00    1   2
476 15/09/2015  06:55:00    1   2
477 15/09/2015  06:56:00    1   2
478 15/09/2015  06:57:00    1   2
479 15/09/2015  06:58:00    1   2
480 15/09/2015  06:59:00    1   2
481 15/09/2015  07:00:00    1   2
482 15/09/2015  07:01:00    1   2
483 15/09/2015  07:02:00    1   2
484 15/09/2015  07:03:00    1   2
485 15/09/2015  07:04:00    1   2
486 15/09/2015  07:05:00    1   2
487 15/09/2015  07:06:00    1   2
488 15/09/2015  07:07:00    2   3
489 15/09/2015  07:08:00    2   3
490 15/09/2015  07:09:00    2   3
491 15/09/2015  07:10:00    2   3
492 15/09/2015  07:11:00    2   3
493 15/09/2015  07:12:00    2   3
494 15/09/2015  07:13:00    2   3
495 15/09/2015  07:14:00    2   3
496 15/09/2015  07:15:00    2   3
497 15/09/2015  07:16:00    2   3
498 15/09/2015  07:17:00    2   3
499 15/09/2015  07:18:00    2   3
500 15/09/2015  07:19:00    2   3
501 15/09/2015  07:20:00    2   3
502 15/09/2015  07:21:00    2   3
503 15/09/2015  07:22:00    2   3
504 15/09/2015  07:23:00    2   3
505 15/09/2015  07:24:00    2   3
506 15/09/2015  07:25:00    2   3
507 15/09/2015  07:26:00    2   3
508 15/09/2015  07:27:00    2   3
509 15/09/2015  07:28:00    2   3
510 15/09/2015  07:29:00    2   3
511 15/09/2015  07:30:00    2   3
512 15/09/2015  07:31:00    2   3
513 15/09/2015  07:32:00    2   3
514 15/09/2015  07:33:00    2   3
515 15/09/2015  07:34:00    2   3
516 15/09/2015  07:35:00    2   3
517 15/09/2015  07:36:00    2   3
518 15/09/2015  07:37:00    2   3
519 15/09/2015  07:38:00    2   3
520 15/09/2015  07:39:00    2   3
521 15/09/2015  07:40:00    2   3
522 15/09/2015  07:41:00    2   3
523 15/09/2015  07:42:00    2   3
524 15/09/2015  07:43:00    2   3
525 15/09/2015  07:44:00    2   3
526 15/09/2015  07:45:00    2   3
527 15/09/2015  07:46:00    2   3
528 15/09/2015  07:47:00    2   3
529 15/09/2015  07:48:00    2   3
530 15/09/2015  07:49:00    2   3
531 15/09/2015  07:50:00    2   3
532 15/09/2015  07:51:00    2   3
533 15/09/2015  07:52:00    2   3
534 15/09/2015  07:53:00    2   3
535 15/09/2015  07:54:00    2   3
536 15/09/2015  07:55:00    2   3
537 15/09/2015  07:56:00    2   3
538 15/09/2015  07:57:00    2   3
539 15/09/2015  07:58:00    2   3
540 15/09/2015  07:59:00    2   3
541 15/09/2015  08:00:00    2   3
542 15/09/2015  08:01:00    2   3
543 15/09/2015  08:02:00    2   3
544 15/09/2015  08:03:00    2   3
545 15/09/2015  08:04:00    2   3
546 15/09/2015  08:05:00    2   3
547 15/09/2015  08:06:00    2   3
548 15/09/2015  08:07:00    2   3
549 15/09/2015  08:08:00    2   3
550 15/09/2015  08:09:00    2   3
551 15/09/2015  08:10:00    2   3
552 15/09/2015  08:11:00    2   3
553 15/09/2015  08:12:00    2   3
554 15/09/2015  08:13:00    2   3
555 15/09/2015  08:14:00    2   3
556 15/09/2015  08:15:00    2   3
557 15/09/2015  08:16:00    2   3
558 15/09/2015  08:17:00    2   3
559 15/09/2015  08:18:00    2   3
560 15/09/2015  08:19:00    2   3
561 15/09/2015  08:20:00    2   3
562 15/09/2015  08:21:00    2   3
563 15/09/2015  08:22:00    2   3
564 15/09/2015  08:23:00    2   3
565 15/09/2015  08:24:00    2   3
566 15/09/2015  08:25:00    2   3
567 15/09/2015  08:26:00    2   3
568 15/09/2015  08:27:00    2   3
569 15/09/2015  08:28:00    2   3
570 15/09/2015  08:29:00    2   3
571 15/09/2015  08:30:00    2   3
572 15/09/2015  08:31:00    2   3
573 15/09/2015  08:32:00    2   3
574 15/09/2015  08:33:00    2   3
575 15/09/2015  08:34:00    2   3
576 15/09/2015  08:35:00    2   3
577 15/09/2015  08:36:00    2   3
578 15/09/2015  08:37:00    2   3
579 15/09/2015  08:38:00    2   3
580 15/09/2015  08:39:00    2   3
581 15/09/2015  08:40:00    2   3
582 15/09/2015  08:41:00    2   3
583 15/09/2015  08:42:00    2   3
584 15/09/2015  08:43:00    2   3
585 15/09/2015  08:44:00    2   3
586 15/09/2015  08:45:00    2   3
587 15/09/2015  08:46:00    2   3
588 15/09/2015  08:47:00    2   3
589 15/09/2015  08:48:00    2   3
590 15/09/2015  08:49:00    2   3
591 15/09/2015  08:50:00    2   3
592 15/09/2015  08:51:00    2   3
593 15/09/2015  08:52:00    2   3
594 15/09/2015  08:53:00    2   3
595 15/09/2015  08:54:00    2   3
596 15/09/2015  08:55:00    2   3
597 15/09/2015  08:56:00    2   3
598 15/09/2015  08:57:00    2   3
599 15/09/2015  08:58:00    2   3
600 15/09/2015  08:59:00    2   3
601 15/09/2015  09:00:00    2   3
602 15/09/2015  09:01:00    2   3
603 15/09/2015  09:02:00    2   3
604 15/09/2015  09:03:00    2   3
605 15/09/2015  09:04:00    2   3
606 15/09/2015  09:05:00    2   3
607 15/09/2015  09:06:00    2   3
608 15/09/2015  09:07:00    2   3
609 15/09/2015  09:08:00    2   3
610 15/09/2015  09:09:00    2   3
611 15/09/2015  09:10:00    2   3
612 15/09/2015  09:11:00    2   3
613 15/09/2015  09:12:00    2   3
614 15/09/2015  09:13:00    2   3
615 15/09/2015  09:14:00    2   3
616 15/09/2015  09:15:00    2   3
617 15/09/2015  09:16:00    2   3
618 15/09/2015  09:17:00    2   3
619 15/09/2015  09:18:00    2   3
620 15/09/2015  09:19:00    2   3
621 15/09/2015  09:20:00    2   3
622 15/09/2015  09:21:00    2   3
623 15/09/2015  09:22:00    2   3
624 15/09/2015  09:23:00    2   3
625 15/09/2015  09:24:00    2   3
626 15/09/2015  09:25:00    2   3
627 15/09/2015  09:26:00    2   3
628 15/09/2015  09:27:00    2   3
629 15/09/2015  09:28:00    2   3
630 15/09/2015  09:29:00    2   3
631 15/09/2015  09:30:00    2   3
632 15/09/2015  09:31:00    2   3
633 15/09/2015  09:32:00    1   2
634 15/09/2015  09:33:00    1   2
635 15/09/2015  09:34:00    1   2
636 15/09/2015  09:35:00    1   2
637 15/09/2015  09:36:00    1   2
638 15/09/2015  09:37:00    1   2
639 15/09/2015  09:38:00    1   2
640 15/09/2015  09:39:00    1   2
641 15/09/2015  09:40:00    1   2
642 15/09/2015  09:41:00    1   2
643 15/09/2015  09:42:00    1   2
644 15/09/2015  09:43:00    1   2
645 15/09/2015  09:44:00    1   2
646 15/09/2015  09:45:00    1   2
647 15/09/2015  09:46:00    1   2
648 15/09/2015  09:47:00    1   2
649 15/09/2015  09:48:00    1   2
650 15/09/2015  09:49:00    1   2
651 15/09/2015  09:50:00    1   2
652 15/09/2015  09:51:00    1   2
653 15/09/2015  09:52:00    1   2
654 15/09/2015  09:53:00    1   2
655 15/09/2015  09:54:00    1   2
656 15/09/2015  09:55:00    1   2
657 15/09/2015  09:56:00    1   2
658 15/09/2015  09:57:00    1   2
659 15/09/2015  09:58:00    1   2
660 15/09/2015  09:59:00    1   2
661 15/09/2015  10:00:00    1   2
662 15/09/2015  10:01:00    1   2
663 15/09/2015  10:02:00    1   2
664 15/09/2015  10:03:00    1   2
665 15/09/2015  10:04:00    1   2
666 15/09/2015  10:05:00    1   2
667 15/09/2015  10:06:00    1   2
668 15/09/2015  10:07:00    1   2
669 15/09/2015  10:08:00    1   2
670 15/09/2015  10:09:00    1   2
671 15/09/2015  10:10:00    1   2
672 15/09/2015  10:11:00    1   2
673 15/09/2015  10:12:00    1   2
674 15/09/2015  10:13:00    1   2
675 15/09/2015  10:14:00    1   2
676 15/09/2015  10:15:00    1   2
677 15/09/2015  10:16:00    1   2
678 15/09/2015  10:17:00    1   2
679 15/09/2015  10:18:00    1   2
680 15/09/2015  10:19:00    1   2
681 15/09/2015  10:20:00    1   2
682 15/09/2015  10:21:00    1   2
683 15/09/2015  10:22:00    1   2
684 15/09/2015  10:23:00    1   2
685 15/09/2015  10:24:00    1   2
686 15/09/2015  10:25:00    1   2
687 15/09/2015  10:26:00    1   2
688 15/09/2015  10:27:00    1   2
689 15/09/2015  10:28:00    1   2
690 15/09/2015  10:29:00    1   2
691 15/09/2015  10:30:00    1   2
692 15/09/2015  10:31:00    1   2
693 15/09/2015  10:32:00    1   2
694 15/09/2015  10:33:00    1   2
695 15/09/2015  10:34:00    1   2
696 15/09/2015  10:35:00    1   2
697 15/09/2015  10:36:00    1   2
698 15/09/2015  10:37:00    1   2
699 15/09/2015  10:38:00    1   2
700 15/09/2015  10:39:00    1   2
701 15/09/2015  10:40:00    1   2
702 15/09/2015  10:41:00    1   2
703 15/09/2015  10:42:00    1   2
704 15/09/2015  10:43:00    1   2
705 15/09/2015  10:44:00    1   2
706 15/09/2015  10:45:00    1   2
707 15/09/2015  10:46:00    1   2
708 15/09/2015  10:47:00    1   2
709 15/09/2015  10:48:00    1   2
710 15/09/2015  10:49:00    1   2
711 15/09/2015  10:50:00    1   2
712 15/09/2015  10:51:00    1   2
713 15/09/2015  10:52:00    1   2
714 15/09/2015  10:53:00    1   2
715 15/09/2015  10:54:00    1   2
716 15/09/2015  10:55:00    1   2
717 15/09/2015  10:56:00    1   2
718 15/09/2015  10:57:00    1   2
719 15/09/2015  10:58:00    1   2
720 15/09/2015  10:59:00    1   2
721 15/09/2015  11:00:00    1   2
722 15/09/2015  11:01:00    1   2
723 15/09/2015  11:02:00    1   2
724 15/09/2015  11:03:00    1   2
725 15/09/2015  11:04:00    1   2
726 15/09/2015  11:05:00    1   2
727 15/09/2015  11:06:00    1   2
728 15/09/2015  11:07:00    1   2
729 15/09/2015  11:08:00    1   2
730 15/09/2015  11:09:00    1   2
731 15/09/2015  11:10:00    1   2
732 15/09/2015  11:11:00    1   2
733 15/09/2015  11:12:00    1   2
734 15/09/2015  11:13:00    1   2
735 15/09/2015  11:14:00    1   2
736 15/09/2015  11:15:00    1   2
737 15/09/2015  11:16:00    1   2
738 15/09/2015  11:17:00    1   2
739 15/09/2015  11:18:00    1   2
740 15/09/2015  11:19:00    1   2
741 15/09/2015  11:20:00    1   2
742 15/09/2015  11:21:00    1   2
743 15/09/2015  11:22:00    1   2
744 15/09/2015  11:23:00    1   2
745 15/09/2015  11:24:00    1   2
746 15/09/2015  11:25:00    1   2
747 15/09/2015  11:26:00    1   2
748 15/09/2015  11:27:00    1   2
749 15/09/2015  11:28:00    1   2
750 15/09/2015  11:29:00    1   2
751 15/09/2015  11:30:00    1   2
752 15/09/2015  11:31:00    1   2
753 15/09/2015  11:32:00    1   2
754 15/09/2015  11:33:00    1   2
755 15/09/2015  11:34:00    1   2
756 15/09/2015  11:35:00    1   2
757 15/09/2015  11:36:00    1   2
758 15/09/2015  11:37:00    2   3
759 15/09/2015  11:38:00    2   3
760 15/09/2015  11:39:00    2   3
761 15/09/2015  11:40:00    2   3
762 15/09/2015  11:41:00    2   3
763 15/09/2015  11:42:00    2   3
764 15/09/2015  11:43:00    2   3
765 15/09/2015  11:44:00    2   3
766 15/09/2015  11:45:00    2   3
767 15/09/2015  11:46:00    2   3
768 15/09/2015  11:47:00    2   3
769 15/09/2015  11:48:00    2   3
770 15/09/2015  11:49:00    2   3
771 15/09/2015  11:50:00    2   3
772 15/09/2015  11:51:00    2   3
773 15/09/2015  11:52:00    2   3
774 15/09/2015  11:53:00    2   3
775 15/09/2015  11:54:00    2   3
776 15/09/2015  11:55:00    2   3
777 15/09/2015  11:56:00    2   3
778 15/09/2015  11:57:00    2   3
779 15/09/2015  11:58:00    2   3
780 15/09/2015  11:59:00    2   3
781 15/09/2015  12:00:00    2   3
782 15/09/2015  12:01:00    2   3
783 15/09/2015  12:02:00    2   3
784 15/09/2015  12:03:00    2   3
785 15/09/2015  12:04:00    2   3
786 15/09/2015  12:05:00    2   3
787 15/09/2015  12:06:00    2   3
788 15/09/2015  12:07:00    2   3
789 15/09/2015  12:08:00    2   3
790 15/09/2015  12:09:00    2   3
791 15/09/2015  12:10:00    2   3
792 15/09/2015  12:11:00    2   3
793 15/09/2015  12:12:00    2   3
794 15/09/2015  12:13:00    2   3
795 15/09/2015  12:14:00    2   3
796 15/09/2015  12:15:00    2   3
797 15/09/2015  12:16:00    2   3
798 15/09/2015  12:17:00    2   3
799 15/09/2015  12:18:00    2   3
800 15/09/2015  12:19:00    2   3
801 15/09/2015  12:20:00    2   3
802 15/09/2015  12:21:00    2   3
803 15/09/2015  12:22:00    2   3
804 15/09/2015  12:23:00    2   3
805 15/09/2015  12:24:00    2   3
806 15/09/2015  12:25:00    2   3
807 15/09/2015  12:26:00    2   3
808 15/09/2015  12:27:00    2   3
809 15/09/2015  12:28:00    2   3
810 15/09/2015  12:29:00    2   3
811 15/09/2015  12:30:00    2   3
812 15/09/2015  12:31:00    2   3
813 15/09/2015  12:32:00    2   3
814 15/09/2015  12:33:00    2   3
815 15/09/2015  12:34:00    2   3
816 15/09/2015  12:35:00    2   3
817 15/09/2015  12:36:00    2   3
818 15/09/2015  12:37:00    2   3
819 15/09/2015  12:38:00    2   3
820 15/09/2015  12:39:00    2   3
821 15/09/2015  12:40:00    2   3
822 15/09/2015  12:41:00    2   3
823 15/09/2015  12:42:00    2   3
824 15/09/2015  12:43:00    2   3
825 15/09/2015  12:44:00    2   3
826 15/09/2015  12:45:00    2   3
827 15/09/2015  12:46:00    2   3
828 15/09/2015  12:47:00    2   3
829 15/09/2015  12:48:00    2   3
830 15/09/2015  12:49:00    2   3
831 15/09/2015  12:50:00    2   3
832 15/09/2015  12:51:00    2   3
833 15/09/2015  12:52:00    2   3
834 15/09/2015  12:53:00    2   3
835 15/09/2015  12:54:00    2   3
836 15/09/2015  12:55:00    2   3
837 15/09/2015  12:56:00    2   3
838 15/09/2015  12:57:00    2   3
839 15/09/2015  12:58:00    2   3
840 15/09/2015  12:59:00    2   3
841 15/09/2015  13:00:00    2   3
842 15/09/2015  13:01:00    2   3
843 15/09/2015  13:02:00    2   3
844 15/09/2015  13:03:00    2   3
845 15/09/2015  13:04:00    2   3
846 15/09/2015  13:05:00    2   3
847 15/09/2015  13:06:00    2   3
848 15/09/2015  13:07:00    2   3
849 15/09/2015  13:08:00    2   3
850 15/09/2015  13:09:00    2   3
851 15/09/2015  13:10:00    2   3
852 15/09/2015  13:11:00    2   3
853 15/09/2015  13:12:00    2   3
854 15/09/2015  13:13:00    2   3
855 15/09/2015  13:14:00    1   2
856 15/09/2015  13:15:00    1   2
857 15/09/2015  13:16:00    1   2
858 15/09/2015  13:17:00    1   2
859 15/09/2015  13:18:00    1   2
860 15/09/2015  13:19:00    1   2
861 15/09/2015  13:20:00    1   2
862 15/09/2015  13:21:00    1   2
863 15/09/2015  13:22:00    1   2
864 15/09/2015  13:23:00    1   2
865 15/09/2015  13:24:00    1   2
866 15/09/2015  13:25:00    1   2
867 15/09/2015  13:26:00    1   2
868 15/09/2015  13:27:00    1   2
869 15/09/2015  13:28:00    1   2
870 15/09/2015  13:29:00    1   2
871 15/09/2015  13:30:00    1   2
872 15/09/2015  13:31:00    1   2
873 15/09/2015  13:32:00    1   2
874 15/09/2015  13:33:00    1   2
875 15/09/2015  13:34:00    1   2
876 15/09/2015  13:35:00    1   2
877 15/09/2015  13:36:00    1   2
878 15/09/2015  13:37:00    1   2
879 15/09/2015  13:38:00    1   2
880 15/09/2015  13:39:00    1   2
881 15/09/2015  13:40:00    1   2
882 15/09/2015  13:41:00    1   2
883 15/09/2015  13:42:00    1   2
884 15/09/2015  13:43:00    1   2
885 15/09/2015  13:44:00    1   2
886 15/09/2015  13:45:00    1   2
887 15/09/2015  13:46:00    1   2
888 15/09/2015  13:47:00    1   2
889 15/09/2015  13:48:00    1   2
890 15/09/2015  13:49:00    2   3
891 15/09/2015  13:50:00    2   3
892 15/09/2015  13:51:00    2   3
893 15/09/2015  13:52:00    2   3
894 15/09/2015  13:53:00    2   3
895 15/09/2015  13:54:00    2   3
896 15/09/2015  13:55:00    2   3
897 15/09/2015  13:56:00    2   3
898 15/09/2015  13:57:00    2   3
899 15/09/2015  13:58:00    2   3
900 15/09/2015  13:59:00    2   3
901 15/09/2015  14:00:00    2   3
902 15/09/2015  14:01:00    2   3
903 15/09/2015  14:02:00    2   3
904 15/09/2015  14:03:00    2   3
905 15/09/2015  14:04:00    2   3
906 15/09/2015  14:05:00    2   3
907 15/09/2015  14:06:00    2   3
908 15/09/2015  14:07:00    2   3
909 15/09/2015  14:08:00    2   3
910 15/09/2015  14:09:00    2   3
911 15/09/2015  14:10:00    2   3
912 15/09/2015  14:11:00    2   3
913 15/09/2015  14:12:00    2   3
914 15/09/2015  14:13:00    2   3
915 15/09/2015  14:14:00    2   3
916 15/09/2015  14:15:00    2   3
917 15/09/2015  14:16:00    2   3
918 15/09/2015  14:17:00    2   3
919 15/09/2015  14:18:00    2   3
920 15/09/2015  14:19:00    2   3
921 15/09/2015  14:20:00    2   3
922 15/09/2015  14:21:00    2   3
923 15/09/2015  14:22:00    2   3
924 15/09/2015  14:23:00    2   3
925 15/09/2015  14:24:00    2   3
926 15/09/2015  14:25:00    2   3
927 15/09/2015  14:26:00    2   3
928 15/09/2015  14:27:00    2   3
929 15/09/2015  14:28:00    2   3
930 15/09/2015  14:29:00    2   3
931 15/09/2015  14:30:00    2   3
932 15/09/2015  14:31:00    2   3
933 15/09/2015  14:32:00    2   3
934 15/09/2015  14:33:00    2   3
935 15/09/2015  14:34:00    2   3
936 15/09/2015  14:35:00    2   3
937 15/09/2015  14:36:00    2   3
938 15/09/2015  14:37:00    2   3
939 15/09/2015  14:38:00    2   3
940 15/09/2015  14:39:00    2   3
941 15/09/2015  14:40:00    2   3
942 15/09/2015  14:41:00    2   3
943 15/09/2015  14:42:00    2   3
944 15/09/2015  14:43:00    2   3
945 15/09/2015  14:44:00    2   3
946 15/09/2015  14:45:00    2   3
947 15/09/2015  14:46:00    2   3
948 15/09/2015  14:47:00    2   3
949 15/09/2015  14:48:00    2   3
950 15/09/2015  14:49:00    2   3
951 15/09/2015  14:50:00    2   3
952 15/09/2015  14:51:00    2   3
953 15/09/2015  14:52:00    2   3
954 15/09/2015  14:53:00    2   3
955 15/09/2015  14:54:00    1   2
956 15/09/2015  14:55:00    1   2
957 15/09/2015  14:56:00    1   2
958 15/09/2015  14:57:00    1   2
959 15/09/2015  14:58:00    1   2
960 15/09/2015  14:59:00    1   2
961 15/09/2015  15:00:00    1   2
962 15/09/2015  15:01:00    1   2
963 15/09/2015  15:02:00    1   2
964 15/09/2015  15:03:00    1   2
965 15/09/2015  15:04:00    1   2
966 15/09/2015  15:05:00    1   2
967 15/09/2015  15:06:00    1   2
968 15/09/2015  15:07:00    1   2
969 15/09/2015  15:08:00    1   2
970 15/09/2015  15:09:00    1   2
971 15/09/2015  15:10:00    1   2
972 15/09/2015  15:11:00    1   2
973 15/09/2015  15:12:00    0   1
974 15/09/2015  15:13:00    0   1
975 15/09/2015  15:14:00    0   1
976 15/09/2015  15:15:00    0   1
977 15/09/2015  15:16:00    0   1
978 15/09/2015  15:17:00    0   1
979 15/09/2015  15:18:00    0   1
980 15/09/2015  15:19:00    0   1
981 15/09/2015  15:20:00    0   1
982 15/09/2015  15:21:00    0   1
983 15/09/2015  15:22:00    0   1
984 15/09/2015  15:23:00    0   1
985 15/09/2015  15:24:00    0   1
986 15/09/2015  15:25:00    0   1
987 15/09/2015  15:26:00    0   1
988 15/09/2015  15:27:00    0   1
989 15/09/2015  15:28:00    0   1
990 15/09/2015  15:29:00    0   1
991 15/09/2015  15:30:00    0   1
992 15/09/2015  15:31:00    0   1
993 15/09/2015  15:32:00    0   1
994 15/09/2015  15:33:00    0   1
995 15/09/2015  15:34:00    0   1
996 15/09/2015  15:35:00    0   1
997 15/09/2015  15:36:00    0   1
998 15/09/2015  15:37:00    0   1
999 15/09/2015  15:38:00    0   1
1000    15/09/2015  15:39:00    0   1
1001    15/09/2015  15:40:00    0   1
1002    15/09/2015  15:41:00    0   1
1003    15/09/2015  15:42:00    0   1
1004    15/09/2015  15:43:00    0   1
1005    15/09/2015  15:44:00    0   1
1006    15/09/2015  15:45:00    0   1
1007    15/09/2015  15:46:00    0   1
1008    15/09/2015  15:47:00    0   1
1009    15/09/2015  15:48:00    0   1
1010    15/09/2015  15:49:00    0   1
1011    15/09/2015  15:50:00    0   1
1012    15/09/2015  15:51:00    0   1
1013    15/09/2015  15:52:00    0   1
1014    15/09/2015  15:53:00    0   1
1015    15/09/2015  15:54:00    0   1
1016    15/09/2015  15:55:00    0   1
```

Here is the code I used:

```
A9$Code_Activity1 <- factor(A9$Code_Activity1, levels = c(1,2,3), labels= c("Non-working hours", "At work", "Driving"))  

ggplot(A9, aes(x = Time, y = Code_response*10+10, ymax = Code_response*10+10, ymin = 0)) + 
geom_ribbon(data = A9, aes(x = Time, y = Code_response+5, fill = Code_Activity1, stat = "count", na.rm = FALSE), alpha = 0.4) + 
facet_wrap(~Date, nrow = 20)
```

My plot looks like this:
[image]

I am expecting more green (indicating at work period, coded as '2') ribbons in-between the blue ribbons (indicating driving period, coded as '3')

It looks like ggplot doesn't seem to recognise all the activity periods. I am new to ggplot, unfortunately I haven't found similar solutions to my problem here. I wonder how I should tackle this?

Many thanks,
Cyb

Comment: can you add the output of  `dput(your_dataframe)` as an edit to you question?

Comment: Can you give a sample of your dataset that shows the problem?  The one you currently have seems to plot OK.

Comment: It seems that the factors levels don't match. `At work` seems to be plotted as blue, instead of green, as shown by the legend. The error could come from the levels recoding.

Comment: A full day dataset could be great, to see the 3 `Code_response` and the transitions.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, are there ways that I can share the full data file with you here? Cyb

Comment: Do you have a larger dataframe than A9 ? Could you provide a `dput` of a larger fragment of it ?

Comment: I added a larger fragment of my data A9 on the post. Thanks.

Comment: Just saw that for the "2015-09-15", you have a blue peak at 14:45, with a different color. The blue color you see in the middle of the day is the overlap of blue and green (with your alpha = 0.4), giving a strange color, not present in your legend by the way.

Comment: Is it volunteer to have overlaps for colors : http://i.stack.imgur.com/h3I5V.jpg ?

Comment: As it is a categorical/ Discrete data, we shouldn't expect an overlap of colours..? It looks like that ggplot only recognises the min and max time of each activity category on 15/9/2015. I updated alpha = 1 so now I can see ribbons with distinct colours. Though I still don't manage to see more green ribbons e.g. a missing green ribbon during 09:32-11:35.

Comment: It is, because you used `geom_ribbon`, see `geom_bar`.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentionned in comment, the different colors overlap in your plot, giving strange colors, see with your data :

[image]

```
A9$TOA = as.POSIXct(paste0(str_sub(A9$Date, 7,10), "-" , str_sub(A9$Date, 4,5), "-", str_sub(A9$Date, 1,2), " ", A9$Time))

A9$Code_Activity1 <- factor(A9$Code_Activity1, levels = c(1,2,3), labels= c("Non-working hours", "At work", "Driving"))  

ggplot(A9, aes(x = TOA, y = Code_response*10+10, ymax = Code_response*10+10, ymin = 0)) + 
geom_ribbon(data = A9, aes(y = Code_response+5, fill = Code_Activity1, stat = "count", na.rm = FALSE), alpha = 0.4)
```

In your case, you might prefer `geom_bar`:

[image]

```
ggplot(A9, aes(x = TOA, y = Code_response + 5, fill = Code_Activity1)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for looking this up (and adjusting time display on x-axis too)! I edited the y-axis so that the height of activity also represent Code_response output You can see the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoF4h.jpg)